# What would be the best way to automate rsync's password input?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

Consider I have two machines and I use rsync to pull files from machine B to machine A. If I'm running the system call from machine A, what would be a good way to automate the password input from machine A?

Both machines currently run Ubuntu 16.04 and must remain so.

Comment: presumably the connection is over ssh. So you can use [authorized keys with forced command and source restriction](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/openssh)

Comment: Did rsync over ssh with RSA keys and it worked.